# Lower trailing parts of letters "g" and "y" etc hidden/cut off/overwritten in ggplot labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, terminology

The bottom parts of the "y"'s and "g"'s are cut off in this map.  See "dryland" and "irrigated" under soy.

[image]

What setting controls this?  Here is my `theme_map` function

```
theme_map <- function (base_size = 12, base_family = "") {
  theme_gray(base_size = base_size, base_family = base_family) %+replace% 
    theme(
      axis.line=element_blank(),
      axis.text.x=element_blank(),
      axis.text.y=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks=element_blank(),
      axis.ticks.length=unit(0.3, "lines"),
      axis.ticks.margin=unit(0.5, "lines"),
      axis.title.x=element_blank(),
      axis.title.y=element_blank(),
      legend.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour=NA),
      legend.key=element_rect(colour="white"),
      legend.key.size=unit(1.2, "lines"),
      legend.position="right",
      legend.text=element_text(size=rel(0.8)),
      legend.title=element_text(size=rel(0.8), face="bold", hjust=0),
      panel.background=element_blank(),
      panel.border=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
      panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
      panel.spacing=unit(0, "lines"),
      plot.background=element_blank(),
      plot.margin=unit(c(1, 1, 0.5, 0.5), "lines"),
      plot.title=element_text(size=rel(1.2)),
      strip.background=element_rect(fill="white", colour="white"),
      strip.text.x=element_text(size=rel(.8)),
      strip.text.y=element_text(size=rel(0.8), angle=-90) 
    )   
}
```

I am just dipping my toe into `ggplot2` after spending a long time as a curmudgeonly devotee of base graphics.  I found that `theme_map` function on the internet somewhere, so I don't understand it yet.  Can someone please tell me which of those settings I'd need to tweak to solve my problem?

Here's my code for generating (one of) those maps, but I'm assuming that the relevant part is in the `theme_map` function

```
mapcorn <- ggplot(USA_fort_premade) + 
    aes(long,lat,group=group) + 
    geom_polygon(aes(x=long,y=lat, group=group, fill=yield.mean), 
                 data=REAP_fort_corn)+
    geom_path(color="grey", lwd = .1) +
    coord_fixed(1.3) +
    facet_wrap( ~ irr) +
    scale_fill_gradient2(low = rgb(.9, .4, 0), mid = rgb(.9, .9, 0),
                         high = rgb(0,.8,0), midpoint = mean(REAP_fort_corn$yield.mean, na.rm = TRUE), 
                         space = "Lab", name = "bu/ac",
                         na.value = "grey50", guide = "colourbar") +
    theme_map() +ggtitle("Corn")
```

Apologies for not reproducible, but the data is huge and this should be a fairly simple question.  A hard one to google however if you don't know the terms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If those are the facet strip labels, try `strip.text.x=element_text(margin=margin(b=5))`, where `b` is the bottom margin in points. Set it to whatever value is large enough to get the complete text to appear. You can adjust the top, right, bottom, and left margins with `margin=margin(t=5, r=2, b=7, l=2)`, or whatever values work for your plot.

Comment: I also ran across this issue today, still a problem. Maybe it should be raised as an issue on github.